# Common algorithm for Long and Integer

Tags: java

My Idea shows that I have common code for two classes and I should make it one due to DRY rule (Don't Repeat Yourself).

```
class LongPersistence {
    public void storeSomeNiceNumber(@NotNull Long l) {
            if (l < 0) {
                throw new RuntimeException("value should not be negative");
            }
            someNicePersistence.store(new String(l).getBytes());
        }
    }

    public Long retrieveSomeNiceNumber() {
        try {
            byte[] bytesRepr someNicePersistence.retrieve();
            Long value = Long.parseLong(new String(bytesRepr));
            return value;
        } catch (SomeNicePersistenceException e) {
            return 0L;
        }
    }
}
```

So i started working...

```
class Persistence<N extends Number> {
```

... and failed as:

1. Number cannot be compared to 0.
2. I cannot return 0 to a Number.

I think this should be possible in well-defined langue, as Java I had been considering so far. Am I missing something? Please advise how to make this algorithm common to Long and Integer (and as an A+ task for any Number)

Comment: There are some things that are best done separately. I understand what you want to do, though.

Comment: If you’re sure you will only have Long and Integer subclasses, you can just call the Number’s `longValue()` method and compare that to zero.  However, if there is any possibility that you will add subclasses for float, double, BigDecimal, or BigInteger, comparing `longValue()` will not be sufficient, as it will produce incorrect results for values between -1 and 0 such as -0.5 (or in BigInteger’s case, negative numbers whose 63rd bit is zero).

Comment: @VGR it's strange that Java's Number does not implement signum() as it is a basic CPU operation to get the sign bit. Also neutral value 0 could be done. This I can do by using functional interface for parsing, and parse "0", however I was hoping that you guys will come up with somehow refreshed interface in Java, that I am not aware of yet.

Comment: Primitive wrapper classes aren’t really intended for doing math;  they are mostly for allowing primitive values to be placed in containers that require objects, like Collections and Maps.

Comment: @VGR thanks that cleaned a bit things in my head. I required to too much from the java.lang.Number - instead I will externalize math to another class.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @VGR I understood that I required math logic from java.lang.Number class which is intended to store numbers as Objects only (something like a Variant type), therefore I have externalized the math to another interface, which in my opinion makes more sense.

```
public interface NumberMath<E extends Number> {
    E parse(String string);
    String toString(E e);
    E zero();
    int signum(E e);
}

class NumberPersistence<E extends Number> {

    private final NumberMath<E> math;
    private final SomeNicePersistence someNicePersistence;

    public NumberPersistence(NumberMath<E> math, SomeNicePersistence persistence) {
        this.someNicePersistence = persistence;
        this.math = math;
    }

    public void storeSomeNiceNumber(E l) {

        if (math.signum(l) < 0) {
            throw new RuntimeException("value should not be negative");
        }
        someNicePersistence.store(math.toString(l).getBytes());

    }

    public E retrieveSomeNiceNumber() {

        try {
            byte[] bytesRepr = someNicePersistence.retrieve();
            E value = math.parse(new String(bytesRepr));
            return value;
        } catch (SomeNicePersistenceException e) {
            return math.zero();
        }
    }
}
```

I have bounded the E to Number, but to be honest, in this case it is not required anymore.